# Can't get bootstrap scrollspy to work in a new MVC app

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, scrollspy

I've been doing some learning lately and bootstrap has been part of that. I have a simple (but long) web page that I thought would be good to use scrollspy with but I just couldn't get anything to work right. I figured I'd start with something that worked, but still had troubles. The primary problem is that the text and the scrollspy were overlapping. I figured maybe it was something I messed up.

So...

I created an out of the box MVC 4 site. Courtesy of someone else on SO I found this trivial example http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/rWYQu/ and replaced the content of the About.cshtml page with the html code, added a  section just before that to accommodate the css data. This is what I have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<style>
    .content section {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-bottom:20px;
    height:750px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="side-nav" class="span3">
            <ul class="nav nav-list affix">
                <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span9 content">
            <section id="one">
                Section 1
            </section>
            <section id="two">
                Section 2
            </section>
            <section id="three">
                Section 3
            </section>
            <section id="four">
                Section 4
            </section>
            <section id="five">
                Section 5
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Behold! I got exactly what I was getting with my previously edited page: overlapping scrollspy and content. The working sample when dropped in a virgin MVC4 app doesn't work correctly. I'm not exactly sure what the fix is (I'm still learning).

What's the fix?

Comment: Just to make sure, you know that the example you give is using Bootstrap 2 and not the current version (3)?

Comment: The version of bootstrap I am using is 3. If that sample code applies to bootstrap 2, then I wasn't really aware of that. So I guess that means that that code should be different. So much for relying on a simple sample. :-P

Comment: Ho it that's the case, then no doubt, the span* class has been replaced by col-*-* class. The best thing in that case is rely on bootstrap site itself : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: I used a version 3 sample from here http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=scrollspy dropped into that same new program and the formatting was off and the text never lined up right. I guess I follow that link to scrollspy you gave.

Comment: Let us know how you go, I can give an hand for the bootstrap 3 version.

Comment: Things improved when I used the example from tutorialrepublic. However, by default the MVC app has a nav-bar at the top and the scrollspy seems to want to move the text to align with the top of the window (and thus under the nav-bar). Any idea how to compensate for that?

Comment: Can you add the code in your question please?

Comment: It seems I can't. Despite pasting the code with the proper indents and the preview showing correctly, SO tells me I can't submit the properly formatted code because it's not properly formatted. But the link to tutorialrepublic will show what I'm using. But that might be beside the point. The scrollspy doesn't seem to account for the bootstrap nav-bar on the page. When you click a link, the text scrolls so that it is at the top of the window and that's where the nav-bar is, so the top of the text is covered. Something needs adjusting, but I don't know what.

Comment: could you put your code in a jsfiddle, save, and copy/past he link here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OK, I initially balked at that, but then thought "wth, I'm not sleepy yet" so I gave it a try. Try what I'm seeing here: http://jsfiddle.net/c8gp5oa4/2/ and click entries or scroll. The nav-bar is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it on your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/c8gp5oa4/4/

remove the width 140px; in nav-tab, expand a little bit and manage small screen with max-width

```
 ul.nav-tabs {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
    max-width:150px;
    width:100%;
}
```

and change the bootstrap columns to fit screen :

```
<div class="col-xs-3" id="myScrollspy">...
<div class="col-xs-9">...
```

Comment: I went to the fiddle you linked above and that, too, still exhibited the problem. Click on "Section 2" button and it scrolls, but the header text "Section 2" and part of the first line in the section are obscured by the nav-bar. That's the part needing fixing and I'm still stuck. :-(